# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack arount the variable 's' was corrupted

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I try to copy a string, the program works but I get an error:

```
"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack arount the variable 's' was corrupted"
```

Could you help me figure out why?

```
void str_cpy(char **s, char *org) 
{
    *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(org)+1));
    while (*org) 
    {
       *s = org;
       s++
       org++;
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW: This is what [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strdup.html) is for.

Comment: The condition doesn't guarantee that you won't write to an *invalid address*.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart strdup doesn't exist in all standards.

Comment: @user3328621 There is a missing semicolon in the source.

Comment: @MrLister *"strdup() conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001"* [(ref)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) I think it's pretty safe to use.

Comment: The semicolon is actually not missing in the program.. I only copied it here like an idiot...

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing `s`, but I think you want to be incrementing `*s` (but not actually affecting what's returned). I would just use a temporary pointer for the copy. Also, don't forget the NUL-terminator.

```
void str_cpy(char **s, char *org) 
{
    char* newptr;
    if (!s || !org) return;

    newptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(org)+1));
    *s = newptr;

    while (*org) 
    {
       *newptr++ = *org++;
    }
    *newptr = '\0';
}
```

Comment: @user3328621 I think Jonathan phat-fingered a missing `*`. Look again.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm apparently blind... where's the missing `*`? ...... Ah you fixed it, thank you!

Comment: @user3328621 What compiler are you using? My mistake should have generated a nasty warning. Make sure you have a reasonable error-reporting level (for GCC never use less than `-Wall`), and *heed the warnings* it gives you.

Comment: @user3328621 No problem. If answer(s)  help you with your problem they likely deserve an uptick (those little arrows at the top-left of the answer). If it is *the* answer you're looking for, thump the green-check as well. Thanks. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
void str_cpy(char **s, char *org) 
{
    size_t len;

    if (!org) { *s = NULL; return; }
    len = strlen(org);

    *s = malloc(len+1);
    if (*s) memcpy (*s, org, len+1);
}
```

NOTE: there is a special thing about this *solution* : there are no loops, just calls to the std libraries, which are known to be well behaved.